# Connecting bluetooth with HC06 fails over and over again, although it is visible

Tags: python, bluetooth

For a recent project I try to make a python program that let me connect with the HC06 module. For that I use pybluez. But this wont work at all, so I tried to pair through terminal using bluetoothctl.

When scanning I discover the device:

> [NEW] Device 98:D3:31:FD:9A:27 OKEY DOKEY MARIO

but when connecting:

> [bluetooth]# connect 98:D3:31:FD:9A:27
>
> Attempting to connect to 98:D3:31:FD:9A:27
>
> Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
>
> [bluetooth]# connect OKEY DOKEY MARIO
>
> Device OKEY DOKEY MARIO not available

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did above works fine. I just needed an external USB bluetooth dongle. So the bluetooth module on my pc was the problem. Now I can connect and send messages. I used this small program to test the connection, send and then print the time for sending and receiving the message. Code is written in python.

```
    import bluetooth
    import socket
    import time

    import timeit

    size = 1024
    bd_addr = "98:D3:31:FD:9A:27"
    port = 1



    sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
    sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
    time.sleep(5)
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    sock.send("hello!! \r\n")


    while 1:  
       data = sock.recv(size)
       if data:
          end = timeit.default_timer()
          print(data)
          print(end-start)

    sock.close()
```